# SQL rewrite to optimize

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I'm trying to optimize or change the SQL to work with inner joins rather than independent calls

Database: one invoice can have many payment records and order (products) records

Original:

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceNum, 
    (SELECT SUM(Orders.Cost) FROM Orders WHERE Orders.Invoice = InvoiceNum  and Orders.Returned <> 1 GROUP BY Orders.Invoice) as vat_only, 
    (SELECT SUM(Orders.Vat) FROM Orders WHERE Orders.Invoice = InvoiceNum and Orders.Returned <> 1 GROUP BY Orders.Invoice) as sales_prevat, 
    (SELECT SUM(pay.Amount) FROM Payments as pay WHERE Invoices.InvoiceNum = pay.InvoiceNum ) as income
FROM 
    Invoices 
WHERE 
    InvoiceYear = currentyear
```

I'm sure we can do this another way by grouping and joining tables together. When I tried the SQL statement below, I wasn't getting the same amount (count) of records...I'm thinking in respect to the type of join or where it joins !! but still couldn't get it working after 3 hrs of looking on the screen..

So far I got to...

```
SELECT 
    Invoices.InvoiceNum, 
    Sum(Orders.Cost) AS SumOfCost, 
    Sum(Orders.VAT) AS SumOfVAT, 
    SUM(distinct Payments.Amount) as money
FROM 
    Invoices
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders ON Orders.Invoice = Invoices.InvoiceNum 
LEFT JOIN 
    Payments ON Invoices.InvoiceNum = Payments.InvoiceNum
WHERE 
    Invoices.InvoiceYear = 11 
    AND Orders.Returned <> 1
GROUP BY 
    Invoices.InvoiceNum
```

Sorry for the bad english and I'm not sure what to search for to find if it's already been answered here :D

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: Your `where` clause is obviously different

Comment: Invoice and orders, is in a n-n; n-m; m-n, or m-m relation ?

Comment: @mee What is n-n? Do you mean 1-1?

Comment: @mee Invoice and order are **n-m (1 to many)** as also Invoice and payments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both payments and orders can contain more than one record per invoice you will need to do your aggregates in a subquery to avoid cross joining:

```
SELECT  Invoices.InvoiceNum, o.Cost, o.VAT, p.Amount
FROM    Invoices
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Invoice, Cost = SUM(Cost), VAT = SUM(VAT)
            FROM    Orders
            WHERE   Orders.Returned <> 1
            GROUP BY Invoice
        ) o
            ON o.Invoice = Invoices.InvoiceNum
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  InvoiceNum, Amount = SUM(Amount)
            FROM    Payments
            GROUP BY InvoiceNum
        ) P
            ON P.InvoiceNum = Invoices.InvoiceNum
WHERE   Invoices.InvoiceYear = 11;
```

**ADDENDUM**

To expand on the `CROSS JOIN` comment, imagine this data for an Invoice (1)

**Orders**

```
Invoice     Cost        VAT
1           15.00       3.00
1           10.00       2.00
```

**Payments**

```
InvoiceNum      Amount
1               15.00
1               10.00
```

When you join these tables as you did:

```
SELECT  Orders.*, Payments.Amount
FROM    Invoices
        LEFT JOIN Orders 
            ON Orders.Invoice = Invoices.InvoiceNum 
        LEFT JOIN Payments 
            ON Invoices.InvoiceNum = Payments.InvoiceNum;
```

You end up with:

```
Orders.Invoice  Orders.Cost Orders.Vat  Payments.Amount
1               15.00       3.00        15.00                       
1               10.00       2.00        15.00
1               15.00       3.00        10.00
1               10.00       2.00        10.00
```

i.e. every combination of payments/orders, so for each invoice you would get many more rows than required, which distorts your totals. So even though the original data had £25 of payments, this doubles to £50 because of the two records in the order table. This is why each table needs to be aggregated individually, using DISTINCT would not work in the case there was more than one payment/order for the same amount on a single invoice.

---

One final point with regard to optimisation, you should probably index your tables, If you run the query and display the actual execution plan SSMS will suggest indexes for you, but at a guess the following should improve the performance:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Orders_InvoiceNum ON Orders (Invoice) INCLUDE(Cost, VAT, Returned);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Payments_InvoiceNum ON Payments (InvoiceNum) INCLUDE(Amount);
```

This should allow both subqueries to only use the index on each table, with no bookmark loopup/clustered index scan required.

Comment: Since you were first with the right answer, a little more explanation may garner you upvotes faster. (Compare Gordon Linoff's answer.)

Comment: @ErikE Fair point, I have updated the answer to elaborate on the problem of cross joining, and why each table needs to be aggregated separately.

Comment: Good stuff, I would give you another +1 but already dit it earlier.

Comment: thanx for the explanation too, can I ask that if it's able to optimize this query to a point !! I believe using two subquery would slows it down a little...or is this best way of pulling this off

Comment: This is the best way of doing it, I can't see another way of getting the right data out and removing the subqueries. Indexes, as suggested in my latest edit should help performance if this is still an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that an order has multiple lines for an invoice and it has multiple payments on an invoice (sometimes).  This causes a cross product effect for a given order.  You fix this by pre-summarizing the tables.

A related problem is that the `join` will fail if there are no payments, so you need `left outer join`.

```
select i.InvoiceNum, osum.cost, osum.vat, p.income
from Invoice i left outer join
     (select o.Invoice, sum(o.Cost) as cost, sum(o.vat) as vat
      from orders o
      where Returned <> 1
      group by o.Invoice
     ) osum
     on osum.Invoice = i.InvoiceNum left outer join
     (select p.InvoiceNum, sum(pay.Amount) as income
      from Payments p
      group by p.InvoiceNum
     ) psum
     on psum.InvoiceNum = i.InvoiceNum
where i.InvoiceYear = year(getdate())
```

Two comments:  Is the key field for `orders` really `Invoice` or is it also `InvoiceNum`?  Also, do you have a field `Invoice.InvoiceYear`?  Or do you want `year(i.InvoiceDate)` in the `where` clause?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in orders its Invoice is the key field (I'm not the one who developed the database, sorry) and yes it has explicit year field to determine product release year...

Answer (score 0):

```
    select
          PreQuery.InvoiceNum,
          PreQuery.VAT_Only,
          PreQuery.Sales_Prevat,
          SUM( Pay.Amount ) as Income
       from
          ( select
                  I.InvoiceNum,
                  SUM( O.Cost ) as VAT_Only,
                  SUM( O.Vat ) as sales_prevat
               from 
                  Invoice I
                     Join Orders O
                        on I.InvoiceNum = O.Invoice
                       AND O.Returned <> 1
               where
                  I.InvoiceYear = currentYear 
               group by
                  I.InvoiceNum ) PreQuery
          JOIN Payments Pay
             on PreQuery.InvoiceNum = Pay.InvoiceNum
   group by
      PreQuery.InvoiceNum,
      PreQuery.VAT_Only,
      PreQuery.Sales_Prevat
```

Your "currentYear" reference could be parameterized or you can use from getting the current date from sql function such as

```
Year( GetDate() )
```

Comment: You're missing a `GROUP BY` clause in the outer query--not gonna work. To solve this, the `Payments` table should be in its own derived table--just like GarethD's and Gordon Linoff's solutions.

Comment: I see your update. Unfortunately, unlike in MySQL (which I see is your main DB platform), in SQL Server you can't group by just one column and still do `SELECT *` which includes other non-grouped and non-aggregated columns. To solve this properly, the `Payments` table should be in its own derived table--just like GarethD's and Gordon Linoff's solutions.

Comment: @user2486512, revised to fix group by as this was SQL-Server... one of the engines that requires aggregates/min/max,etc on non group-by columns.

Comment: Only one subquery, would certainly test it out...and thank you

Comment: Just tested...this also hasn't returned the whole dataset as expected from the original query (I guess we have to use two queries like above)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, note that I haven't tested it, just wipped it out on notepad.  If any of your invoices may not exist in any of the subtables, then use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT InvoiceNum, vat_only, sales_prevat, income
FROM Invoices i
INNER JOIN (SELECT Invoice, SUM(Cost) [vat_only], SUM(Vat) [sales_prevat]
            FROM Orders
            WHERE Returned <> 1
            GROUP BY Invoice) o
    ON i.InvoiceNum = o.Invoice
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amount) [income]
            FROM Payments) p
    ON i.InvoiceNum = p.InvoiceNum 
WHERE i.InvoiceYear = currentyear
```